# ARKit + SceneKit: Object lags when adding to the scene

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, light

In my ARKit project when I'm adding an object to the scene, screen freezes, but next times after this object was deleted - it is added without any lags. The usual approach we used in many similar projects is SceneKit "prepare" method, but this time it doesn't help. Objects I'm adding are 2-5k polygons with diffuse textures about 500px.

What solutions can you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

To preload the right shaders, call 'prepare' on a scene that has the object you want to preload and the same lighting conditions as your final scene destination